# How to incorporate a method in a filewriter

Tags: java, file, methods

I'm having trouble with one of my homework problems, I think i've done everything right up until the last part which is to call the method and write the method to the output file. Here is the assignment:

> Write a method isPrime which takes a number and determines whether the
>   number is prime or not. It returns a Boolean.
>
> Write a main method that asks the user for an input file that contains
>   numbers and an output file name where it will write the prime numbers
>   to.
>
> Main opens the input file and calls isPrime on each number. Main
>   writes the prime numbers to the output file.
>
> Modify main to throw the appropriate exceptions for working with
>   files.

I've tried several different ways to write the method with the output file but I'm not sure exactly how to do it.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the name of the input file?");
    String inputfile = keyboard.nextLine();
    File f = new File(inputfile);
    System.out.println("What is the name of the output file?");
    String outputfile = keyboard.nextLine();
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outputfile);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File(outputfile));
    while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
       pw.write(inputFile.nextLine().isPrime());
       pw.write(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    pw.close();
    inputFile.close();       
}

public static void isPrime (int num) throws IOException {
    boolean flag = false;
    for (int i =2; i <= num/2; i++) {
        if (num % i ==0) {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!flag) 
        System.out.println(num + "is a prime number");
    else 
        System.out.println(num + "is not a prime number");
}
```

I need the program to be able to read a inputfile of a different numbers and then write out to the output file which of those numbers is prime.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is your code working or not ? If not what is the problem ? Does it crash ? What is the error ? It work but the output is not the expected one ? what was the input, the expected output and the actual output ?

Comment: No it's not working, I have an error under isPrime in this line:   pw.write(inputFile.nextLine().isPrime());

Comment: You need to **read** the error. It tells you what's wrong. If you don't understand it, **post** it. It tells us what's wrong.

Comment: The error is for the line is  "Cannot find symbol"   pw.write(inputFile.nextLine().isPrime());

Answer (score 1):

You wrote "inputFile.nextLine().isPrime()". But inputFile.nextLine() gives you back a String. There is no method isPrime() that you can call on a String, therefore you will get a compilation error.
You must first convert it to an integer, pass it to your method, and then deal with the result:

```
isPrime(Integer.parseInt(inputFile.nextLine()));
```

I suggest you just return a message string from your method isPrime() instead of void, then you can deal with it properly:

```
pw.write(isPrime(Integer.parseInt(inputFile.nextLine())));
```

ADDENDUM:
I modified your code so you can see where to add the suggested lines. I also left out unnecessary lines.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the name of the input file?");
    String inputfile = keyboard.nextLine();
    File f = new File(inputfile);
    System.out.println("What is the name of the output file?");
    String outputfile = keyboard.nextLine();
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File(outputfile));
    while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String nextLine = inputFile.nextLine();
        boolean isPrime = isPrime(Integer.parseInt(nextLine));
        if (isPrime) {
           pw.write(nextLine + System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
    pw.close();
    inputFile.close();       
}

public boolean isPrime (int num) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

TODO: put your file-opening code inside a try-catch-finally block and put your close() commands into its finally block. (If you don't know why it should be inside finally, just ask)

Comment: Okay I changed that and the error went away, now when I run the program I get an error after I tell the program the name of the input and output file.  The error is: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:473)
 at cw5_3.CW5_3.main(CW5_3.java:31)
C:\Users\bambo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)"

Comment: Where exactly do I put this line?  isPrime(Integer.parseInt(inputFile.nextLine()));

Comment: @Nitro Maybe you changed your isPrime method to return a String and that string is null in case of flag = false. You could return an empty string instead, but because you don't want empty lines in your output file, you should return a boolean (the flag variable) and skip printing in your main loop if flag is false. Hold on, I will add the modified program to my answer to make it more clear